# Бот не проходит защиту Cloudflare

Tags: python, selenium, python-telegram-bot, cloudflare

Хочу сделать бота для записи в визовый центр, нашел проект на [GitHub](https://github.com/hnavidan/VFSBot.git) , но залогиниться не получается, бот не может пройти cloudflare, как я понял.

```
import time
import threading
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from utils import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from configparser import ConfigParser

class VFSBot:
  def __init__(self):
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')

    self.url = config.get('VFS', 'url')
    self.email_str = config.get('VFS', 'email')
    self.pwd_str = config.get('VFS', 'password')
    self.interval = config.getint('DEFAULT', 'interval')
    self.channel_id = config.get('TELEGRAM', 'channel_id')
    token = config.get('TELEGRAM', 'auth_token')
    admin_ids = list(map(int, config.get('TELEGRAM', 'admin_ids').split(" ")))

    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
    
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(AdminHandler(admin_ids))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", self.start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", self.help))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("quit", self.quit))


    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

def login(self, update, context):
    self.browser.get((self.url))
    
    if "You are now in line." in self.browser.page_source:
       update.message.reply_text("You are now in queue.")
    
    WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
    time.sleep(1)

    self.browser.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='username').send_keys(self.email_str)
    self.browser.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='password').send_keys(self.pwd_str)

    
    #update.message.reply_text("Sending Captcha...")

    captcha_img = self.browser.find_element(by=By.ID, value='content')
    
    self.captcha_filename = 'captcha.png'
    with open(self.captcha_filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(captcha_img.screenshot_as_png)

    captcha = break_captcha()
    
    self.browser.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='CaptchaInputText').send_keys(captcha)
    time.sleep(1)
    self.browser.find_element(by=By.ID, value='btnSubmit').click()
    
    if "Reschedule Appointment" in self.browser.page_source:
        update.message.reply_text("Successfully logged in!")
        while True:
            try:
                self.check_appointment(update, context)
            except WebError:
                update.message.reply_text("An WebError has occured.\nTrying again.")
                raise WebError
            except Offline:
                update.message.reply_text("Downloaded offline version. \nTrying again.")
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                update.message.reply_text("An error has occured: " + e + "\nTrying again.")
                raise WebError
            time.sleep(self.interval)
    elif "Your account has been locked, please login after 2 minutes." in self.browser.page_source:
       update.message.reply_text("Account locked.\nPlease wait 2 minutes.")
       time.sleep(120)
       return
    elif "The verification words are incorrect." in self.browser.page_source:
       #update.message.reply_text("Incorrect captcha. \nTrying again.")
       return
    elif "You are being rate limited" in self.browser.page_source:
        update.message.reply_text("Rate Limited. \nPlease wait 5 minutes.")
        time.sleep(300)
        return
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("An unknown error has occured. \nTrying again.")
        #self.browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="logoutForm"]/a').click()
        raise WebError
```

это часть кода, которая этим занимается, возможно кто-то может мне помочь, т.к до этого я с подобной задачей не сталкивался.